# Where can I find sample chromecast receiver application using expressplay?

Tags: chromecast, custom-receiver

I've been looking for sample **receiver** application for **chromecast** using **expressplay** for encrypted contents but cannot find one. 
Can anyone refer a link to it ?
Thanks in advance for any help.